# 400 (Bad Request) error when using Pushbullet Ephemerals

Tags: python, http, urllib2, pushbullet

I'm working on a simple command-line [Pushbullet](http://pushbullet.com) Python project, and have the following code:

```
from settings import *
import urllib
import urllib2


def pushSms(number, message):
    url = 'https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/ephemerals'
    values = {
        "type": "push",
        "push": {
            "type": "messaging_extension_reply",
            "package_name": "com.pushbullet.android",
            "source_user_iden": settings["PUSHBULLET_USER_IDEN"],
            "target_device_iden": settings["PUSHBULLET_SMS_IDEN"],
            "conversation_iden": number,
            "message": message
        }
    }

    headers = {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + settings["PUSHBULLET_API_KEY"]}

    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response
```

Example usage might be `pushSms("555 555 5555", "Hi there!")`.

This takes advantage of the Pushbullet android app access to SMS, as documented [here](https://docs.pushbullet.com/v2/#ephemerals). I've checked my `settings` variables and they're all valid (in fact, they're currently in use in a JavaScript version of nearly this exact code in [another project of mine](https://github.com/j6k4m8/meteor-todo/blob/master/server/pushbullet.js).

My suspicion is that this is a basic Python syntax/urllib2 misuse or error, but I've been staring/Googling for hours and can't see my error. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for certain (the response from the server may contain more information), but because we accept both form encoded and json requests, you probably need to set the header "Content-Type: application/json" on the request.

If that's not the case, could you post the body of the 400 response?

Comment: Confirmed that adding the content-type header resolved this problem. To wit, using the `requests` library turned out to be far easier than urllib...